# question on a topological space checking connectedness/compactness etc. (CSIR Dec $15$)

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness

For a subset $A$ of the topological space $X$, let $A'$ denotes the union of set $A$ and all those connected components of $X-A $ which are relatively compact in $X$ (i.e. the closure is compact in $X$). Then for every subset $A$ of $X$, what can we say:

$1. A' \text{ is compact.}$

$2. A''=A'.$

$3. A' \text{ is connected.}$

$4.A'=X.$

The question is asked in CSIR-India in Dec 2015 and I tried the question but I could only say something about compactness. As counterexample I took $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $A=\mathbb{Q}$ then I know that $A'=\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$ contains at least singletons as relatively compact connected subsets in $\mathbb{R}$ So my  $A'=\mathbb{R}$, which is not compact. Further I am not getting how to proceed? Please help. Thank You!

Comment: If $X$ is not compact and if $A=X$ then $A'=X$  is not  compact. If $X=A\cup \{b\}$ where $\{b\}$ is open and closed in $X$ then $A'=X$ is not  connected. If $X$ \ $A$ is connected and closed in $X$ but not compact then $X$ \ $A$ is not empty and $A'=A\ne X.$..... If one of the 4 options is true it must be #2.

Comment: No one says "compact in X", but says "compact" because compactness is an intrinsic property of a space. A space Y is compact  regardless of whether or not it is a sub-space of any space X.